# Extract number if lines from file in order of date file name

Tags: command-line, bash, files, sort

I have a folder with csv files whose file names are dates, viz.: `January-01-2018.csv`, `January-02-2018.csv`, ..., `April-30-2018.csv`.

Using Bash preferably, I want to extract the number of lines from each csv file but doing so in order of date.  i.e., I wish to extract the number of lines in `January-01-2018.csv` and then `January-02-2018.csv` ... and then `April-30-2018.csv` and so on.

At the moment, all I have is:

```
for filename in $(ls *.csv); do cat $filename | wc -l >> by_day.dat; done
```

But this does **not** take care of my operation in "ascending order of date".

Any suggestions on how I might accomplish this?  I would like to do this using bash.

Comment: Do the files' modification times have the same order as their textual names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by combining a few common tools:

- `find` to list all .csv files (unordered) and execute a command for each
- `basename` to extract the file name without `.csv` extension from the path
- `date` to interpret the date specification in the file name and convert it to an easily sortable number, like seconds since 1970.
- `echo` to print the calculated number and the real file path in one line for each file
- `sort` to sort the file paths according to this converted date number
- `cut` to extract only the file paths again from the combined list
- `xargs cat` to construct a command by passing all file names in order to the `cat` command for concatenating them.

The complete line looks like this, if all files we want to process are located in a folder named `datecsv`:

```
$ find datecsv/ -name '*.csv' -exec bash -c 'echo "$(date -d "$(basename -s.csv "{}")" +%s) {}"' \; | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2- | xargs cat
2018,1,1,aaa
2018,1,1,bbb
2018,1,2,ccc
2018,1,2,ddd
2018,4,30,eee
2018,4,30,fff
```

My example files producing the output above are these:

```
$ cat datecsv/April-30-2018.csv
2018,4,30,eee
2018,4,30,fff
$ cat datecsv/January-01-2018.csv
2018,1,1,aaa
2018,1,1,bbb
$ cat datecsv/January-02-2018.csv
2018,1,2,ccc
2018,1,2,ddd
```

As you only want the line number of each file, the command for that would look like this:

```
$ find datecsv/ -name '*.csv' -exec bash -c 'echo "$(date -d "$(basename -s.csv "{}")" +%s) {}"' \; | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2- | xargs -n1 wc -l
2 datecsv/January-01-2018.csv
2 datecsv/January-02-2018.csv
2 datecsv/April-30-2018.csv
```

The only change is the last part, where we use `xargs -n1 wc -l` instead of `xargs cat` as above.

*Some notes:* The approach above relies in your file names being a format that `date` can parse. This is the case for the example names you provided, but it might break if the format changes. It also requires the file name to end with a lowercase `.csv`. Not sure if some special characters in file names might break stuff (spaces should probably be safe, newlines will surely break it).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  I did not know about or remember basename and the intricate piping possible.